# Is there a place that has Soukyuu no Fafner: Dead Aggressor subtitles?

Tags: soukyuu-no-fafner

I've been looking for subtitle tracks for Soukyuu no Fafner: Dead Aggressor, but haven't had any luck. I figured I'd ask here in case any of you guys knew.

Comment: in what language? just the subtitles?

Comment: English. Yes, just the subtitles.

Answer (score 1):

If you check [AniDB](http://anidb.net/perl-bin/animedb.pl?show=anime&aid=1806)'s list of subs, there are a whole list of groups that have subs for it.

> - Philosophy-raws
> - ACX
> - E-D
> - Daman
> - Anime-MX
> - Blitz
> - W_B
> - B-A
> - A-E

At the time of this answer, these are the groups which have completely subbed Fafner, according to AniDB.